# Loading big size image in Volley

Tags: android, image, android-volley

I want to download some images from the net and show them in an ImageView .So I am using Volley.
How can I reduce the size of the images before showing them in ImageView. The original size of the images are 640 by 640 and I need to use them as an icon. How can I change their size to 64*64.

The question is not related to memory management.  I just need to know how can I access the bitmap which I have downloaded from Volley.

Answer (score 0):

### The right way:

**If you control the server you're requesting images from:**

Change the actual image on the server: Create a thumbnail version for your images and use it when appropriate.

**If you don't control the server:**

Consider creating a service that will do this for you. Something along the lines of:

1. Ask your image service for an image with a given URL.
2. Image service checks its cache for a thumbnail version for that URL. If it exists returns it.
3. Image service retrieves the image, creates a thumbnail version, caches it and returns it to you.

### The OK way:

Manipulate the image after it has been downloaded to the device. This isn't optimal but better than nothing. Luckily, Volley provides a built in way to achieve this: simply provide a `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` when requesting the image. Something like this (assuming `imageLoader` is your `ImageLoader` and `imageListener` is you listener for this request:

```
imageLoader.get("http://...", imageListener, maxWidth, maxHeight);
```

Remember, the full size image will be downloaded to the device with this solution.